# dont fetch data from free host but work correctly in localhost

Tags: php, android, localhost, android-volley, web-hosting

i have an android application that fetch some data from server with volley and php . my application fetch correctly in localhost but when put php file in free web host like infinityfree.net fetching not work :( . even test url in my browser and fetch correctly! but in my app dosen't work . my internet premision in my manifest is correct . any body have idea?

my php

```
<?php 

include 'dbconfig.php';

 $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
  //creating a query
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT

POWER,
POWER1,
POWER2
FROM turbine_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");

//executing the query 
$stmt->execute();

//binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result(

$t1,
$t2,
$t3
 );

 $boiler = array(); 

 //traversing through all the result 
 while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = array();

 $temp['t1'] = $t1;
 $temp['t2'] = $t2;
 $temp['t3'] = $t3;


 array_push($boiler, $temp);
 }

 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($boiler);
 ?>
```